# .Net Core Web API Handling exception in different layers

Tags: exception, domain-driven-design, webapi

I'm working on a .Net Core 3.1 Web  API with different classic layers (DDD).
We've implmented a global exception handler to catch all the exceptions and send back friendly messages to client.

In my team, we've got different points of view on exception management.
One of us is more abouit only using the global exception middleware.
On my side, I think we should first catch errors on methods and throw the error.
What is the good way to go ?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways can be combined.

The exception middleware covers cases where an exception is thrown by some inner component but never gets catch, hence freeing us from the need to use try/catch blocks.

On the other hand, in some cases you want to use try/catch block, e.g. when you want to implement a retry logic for specific error (of course, if retry also fails you rethrow the exception, letting the middleware handle it).

Comment: That's the way I finally convince my colleague to go. The bloc gives also the opportunity to build some better workflow in response